# How do I create dynamic column names in a WHILE DATE Loop query?

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql, while-loop

Here is my working query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '2021-01-01'
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()
SET @CurrentDate = @StartDate

WHILE (@CurrentDate < @EndDate)
    BEGIN

        SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN [CreatedDateTime] BETWEEN @CurrentDate AND @CurrentDate + 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

        FROM Table
        WHERE OwnedBy = 'Service Desk'
        
        SET @CurrentDate = convert(varchar(30), dateadd(day,6, @CurrentDate), 101);
        
    END
```

which produces the following result:

[image]

I'm trying to create a dynamic column name that shows the Date range for each result.

For example:
The 1st result should have the column name: "Jan 1-Jan 7"
The 2nd result should have the column name: "Jan 8-Jan 14"
etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: For dynamic column names you need dynamic SQL. Why not do that in your front end? Much easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very unusual way to approach this kind of database problem. You might instead consider using two columns, **without loops**, like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME = '20210101';
WITH e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)-- 10*1
,e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b) -- 10*10
,e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2) -- 10*100
,Dates as (
    SELECT DATEADD(d, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY n)-1, @StartDate) AS BaseDate 
    FROM e3 
)
SELECT d.BaseDate As PeriodStart -- datetime value
    , FORMAT(d.BaseDate, 'MMM dd')+ '-' + FORMAT(DATEADD(d, 6, d.BaseDate), 'MMM dd') as PeriodRange -- string value
    , COUNT(t.*) As TicketCount
FROM Dates d
INNER JOIN [Table] t ON t.[CreatedDateTime] >= d.BaseDate 
    AND t.[CreatedDateTime] < DATEADD(d, 7, d.BaseDate)
    AND t.OwnedBy='Service Desk'
WHERE d.BaseDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
GROUP BY d.BaseDate;
```

This is likely to run many times faster, and will generally be easier to consume in client code and reporting tools.

One other notable change in here is instead of a `BETWEEN` expression for six days in the future, I used two separate conditions where the ending condition is an *exclusive* upper bound for seven days in the future, which is also generally the better way to handle date ranges.